# How can I select an element with specific attributes only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, custom-selectors

I need to paste src to image depending on color choice.

Here is my markup:

```
<div data-img="[black-blue.png]" black blue></div>
<div data-img="[black.png]"  black></div>
<div data-img="[blue.png]"  blue></div>
<div data-img="[orange.png]"  orange></div>
<div data-img="[black-blue-orange.png]" black blue orange></div>
<div data-img="[blue-orange.png]" blue orange></div>
<div data-img="[blue-red-orange.png]" blue red orange></div>
```

My script works on elements attributes:

```
var attributes = '';
for(var i = 0; i<activeColorsArray.length; i++ ){
   attributes += '['+activeColorsArray[i]+']';
}
```

Output: `[blue][black]`, for examples. It's works for black&blue item, but it's catch black&blue&orange element too.

`[blue][black]:not([orange])` not working for me because I have 8 colors...

Need something like ONLY THIS selector.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to consider the number of attributes an element has. If you want to target only `blue` and `black` then you target the elements with only 3 attributes (including `data-img` in your case)

```js
activeColorsArray= ['blue','black'];

var attributes = '';
for(var i = 0; i<activeColorsArray.length; i++ ){
   attributes += '['+activeColorsArray[i]+']';
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(attributes);
var items = Array.from(elements);

elements = items.filter((e) => {
 return e.attributes.length == 3;
})

for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  elements[i].style.color="red";
}
```

```html
<div data-img="[black-blue.png]" black blue>black blue</div>
<div data-img="[black.png]"  black>black</div>
<div data-img="[blue.png]"  blue>blue</div>
<div data-img="[orange.png]"  orange>orange</div>
<div data-img="[black-blue-orange.png]" black blue orange>black blue orange</div>
<div data-img="[blue-orange.png]" blue orange>blue orange</div>
<div data-img="[blue-red-orange.png]" blue red orange>blue red orange</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's your exact markup, the CSS attribute selector would work without any JavaScript. This code will match only divs with the `data-img` attribute with a value of exactly `[black-blue.png]`. Trying to select by naked attributes (`div[black][blue] {}`) is not recommended for the exact reason you've described.

```css
div[data-img="[black-blue.png]"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-img="[black-blue.png]" black blue>black blue</div>
<div data-img="[black.png]"  black>black</div>
<div data-img="[blue.png]"  blue>blue</div>
<div data-img="[orange.png]"  orange>orange</div>
<div data-img="[black-blue-orange.png]" black blue orange>black blue orange</div>
<div data-img="[blue-orange.png]" blue orange>blue orange</div>
<div data-img="[blue-red-orange.png]" blue red orange>blue red orange</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nk98tch1/

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It will not work for me. I don't know which color will be select at first. I have the options with 8 colors.